how to pass viewModel as parameter in NavHost compose navigation
I have to following NavHost:
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = Destinations.ComposeEntryPointRoute
) {
   composable<Destinations.HomeRoute> {
       HomeContent()
   }
   composable<Destinations.GradeConverterRoute> {
       GradeConverterScreen(navController = navController, gradeConverterViewModel = DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE)
   }
}

I don't know how to pass the VM into GradeConverterScreen.
I know that, on the Activity, I can do something like:
val gradeConverterViewModel = hiltViewModel<GradeConverterViewModel>() and then pass that val as parameter but I don't want the MainActivity to have instances of every VM that I need.
This is my GradeConverterScreen
@Composable
fun GradeConverterScreen(
    gradeConverterViewModel: GradeConverterViewModel,
    navController: NavController
) {
    GradeConverterContent(navController, gradeConverterViewModel.state)
}

@Composable
fun GradeConverterContent(
    navController: NavController,
    state: GradeConverterState
) {
    Column {
       ......

I have GradeConverterScreen and GradeConverterContent because I know that the best approach is to create two composables: One that takes the VM as parameter and then the other one just takes the state and methods from the VM if needed so in this way I also don't have issues with my @Previews.
My doubt here is: In the NavHost, instead of having to call GradeConverterScreen, I should call GradeConverterContent?? That doesn't really solve my problem because I would still need to pass the VM's state as argument in the NavHost and if I do that, I'd be never calling GradeConverterScreen.
I'm using Hilt to inject VM.
How can I make this work using the two composables approach (Screen and Content)?

Why do you need to pass the ViewModel?

You should use ViewModel instances in the main screen composables, near where the activity, fragment, or navigation graph starts. Don't pass ViewModel instances to other composables. Instead, only pass the data they need

Can you explain why you don't just use viewModel() instead of DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE, as the documentation says?

Use hiltViewModel in your screen level like this
@Composable
fun GradeConverterScreen(
gradeConverterViewModel: GradeConverterViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
navController: NavController
)

in navigation host no need to pass anything
composable<Destinations.GradeConverterRoute> {
   GradeConverterScreen(navController = navController)
}


Please see this post. I recommend you create your view model in parent composable and from it pass logic down the stream.
